# How to insert in database sqlite3

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, sql-insert

I'm having trouble inserting data inside my database..this is my codes looks like..

```
rs = stat.executeQuery("Select * from students;");
while (rs.next()) {
    idNum = rs.getString("idNum");
    stat.executeUpdate(
        "INSERT INTO record VALUES (null,'" + idNum + "','" + descript +
             "'," + value + ",'" + user.getText() + "','" + timeStamp + "')"
                            );
}//while
```

As you can see I want to insert a data for every student `rs = stat.executeQuery("Select * from students;");` and get all their student number `idNum = rs.getString("idNum");` this is what inside the students table:

```
idNum..............Name

11000001.........Leonardo

11000002.........David

11000003.........Robert

11000004.........Anna

11000005.........May
```

now when I get all their idNum I want them to be inserted inside the table record that will looks like this:

```
idNum.........descript.........amount........blablablabla

11000001.......Fee...............30

11000002.......Fee...............30

11000003.......Fee...............30

11000004.......Fee...............30

11000005.......Fee...............30
```

the problem is only the first idNum is being inserted inside the table record like this:

```
idNum.........descript.........amount........blablablabla

11000001.......Fee...............30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single statement to copy the data.
(Using parameters avoids formatting problems with strings containing special characters.)

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
    "INSERT INTO record SELECT NULL, idNum, ?, ?, ?, ? FROM students");
ps.setString(1, descript);
ps.setInt   (2, value);
ps.setString(3, user.getText());
ps.setString(4, timeStamp);
ps.execute();
```

Comment: thank you CL. i really really appreciate it alot.. =]

Answer (score 2):

You shoulkd not use the same statement object stat twice: once you are reusing is to perform the update (in your case the insert) it closes the resultset you are looping over.

Comment: so i just need to remove the stat from this? `stat.executeUpdate(
        "INSERT INTO record VALUES (null,'" + idNum + "','" + descript +
             "'," + value + ",'" + user.getText() + "','" + timeStamp + "')"
                            );`

Answer (score 0):

Use an ArrayList to store all  idNum from students table. Then loop through the list to insert into record table.

Comment: ArrayList list = new ArrayList(); while (rs.next()) {
    list.add(rs.getString("idNum"));} for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){stat2.executeUpdate(
        "INSERT INTO record VALUES (null,'" + list.get(i) + "','" + descript +
             "'," + value + ",'" + user.getText() + "','" + timeStamp + "')"
                            );}

Comment: when i compiled it says ... Blank.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations how can i fix that?

Comment: i guess that is only the warning as you have not specified the object type  that the array collection stores